# Cassandra cqlsh create keyspace hangs

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have a single node cassandra of version 2.1.2.

I use cqlsh to connect to cassandra and type some commands to experiment. At first all commands work until `create keyspace` hanging.

These are my operations.

```
myuser@myhost:~/s/kuankr-feed-api$ cqlsh 192.168.1.160
Connected to Kr Cluster at 192.168.1.160:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> describe keyspaces;

system                  system_auth          OpsCenter    
kuankr_feed_production  kuankr_feed_staging  system_traces

cqlsh> use kuankr_feed_production;
cqlsh:kuankr_feed_production> describe tables;

news_activity  news_timeline  questions_activity  questions_timeline

cqlsh:kuankr_feed_production> select * from news_activity limit 1;

# too long to show

(1 rows)

cqlsh:kuankr_feed_production> create keyspace test with replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};
^C
cqlsh:kuankr_feed_production> create table Cats (name text);
^C
```

The statement `create keyspace test with replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};` hangs and any successive statement hangs. If I exit and reconnect, all statements is ok except `create keyspace`.

I do these experiments because our newsfeed system can query activities but cannot insert or delete activities which use cassandra as storage backend.

After restarting cassandra, I replayed my operations. At this time cassandra responded me immediatelly.

```
cqlsh:kuankr_feed_production> create keyspace test with replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};
cqlsh:kuankr_feed_production> create table Cats (name text);
Bad Request: No PRIMARY KEY specifed (exactly one required)
```

Update0: cassandra log during my operation

```
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-35] 2015-11-29 13:34:17,402 BatchStatement.java:255 - Batch of prepared statements for [kuankr_feed_production.news_timeline] is of size 9400, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 4280.
### similar 'BatchStatement.java:255 - Batch of prepared statements for...' rows across line 56127 to 56206
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-41] 2015-11-29 13:35:48,088 BatchStatement.java:255 - Batch of prepared statements for [kuankr_feed_production.news_timeline] is of size 9400, exceeding specified threshold of 5120 by 4280.
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-11-29 13:35:49,833 ColumnFamilyStore.java:840 - Enqueuing flush of compaction_history: 2800 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:40] 2015-11-29 13:35:49,834 Memtable.java:325 - Writing Memtable-compaction_history@99094617(578 serialized bytes, 20 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit) 
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2015-11-29 13:35:49,838 ColumnFamilyStore.java:840 - Enqueuing flush of sstable_activity: 14523 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap 
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:41] 2015-11-29 13:35:49,839 Memtable.java:325 - Writing Memtable-sstable_activity@718981419(1539 serialized bytes, 610 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:40] 2015-11-29 13:35:49,994 Memtable.java:364 - Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/system-compaction_history-ka-971-Data.db (407 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1448692540025, position=33554217)
INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:41] 2015-11-29 13:35:49,994 Memtable.java:364 - Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/sstable_activity-5a1ff267ace03f128563cfae6103c65e/system-sstable_activity-ka-2847-Data.db (803 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1448692540025, position=33554217)
```

Comment: What were you logs saying when you command was hanged ?

Comment: @Chandrakant please check my update. There is no clue in cassandra logs.

Comment: Are you able to run `select col_1, col_2, col_3... from news_activity limit 1;` where col_1 ect. correspond to columns in the table? Also run `DESC news_activity` and update your question with the results.

Comment: @Nathan check my update. Any statement following `create keyspace` couldn't work.

Comment: From the looks of it you appear to be trying to create a keyspace from within the keyspace kuankr_feed_production.  Have you tried doing that command before you typed in this line "cqlsh> use kuankr_feed_production;"